# How to get the Max Likelihood Estimators for $\theta_1$ & $\theta_2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

There are 3 types of flowers that can grow from planting a seed. 
$$P(\text{Daisy}) = \theta_1$$
$$P(\text{Rose}) = (1-\theta_1)\theta_2$$
$$P(\text{Sunflower}) = (1-\theta_1)(1-\theta_2)$$

the total number of flowers at the end is $n.$ If $X=(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is the number of daisies, roses and sunflowers respectively, what is the probability mass function of $X$?

Edit:
The answer below answered my question about the distribution. How can I find the max likelihood estimators for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$? Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a multinomial distribution. $\qquad$

Comment: You can ask a new question  for the mle of the multinomial distribution with $p_1=..., p_2=..., p_3=...$ That´s no problem.

Comment: There are severals answers according to the mle [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421105/maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-parameters-of-multinomial-distribution). This link should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to confirm the multinomial distribution condition - constrain the probability to space [0,1] and the sum of the probabilities not more than one (i.e., $\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 p_i= 1$).

Hence, if P(Daisy) +
P(Rose) + P(Sunflower) = 1 then the responses ($X$) are from multinomial distribution.

Thus the equation, which you have to check, is $$\theta_1+(1-\theta_1)\theta_2+(1-\theta_1)(1-\theta_2)=1 \quad \dots (1)$$

**Is this true, if $\theta_1,\theta_2 \in \mathbb R$ ?**

If the equation (1) above holds then indeed $X$ is a multinomial distributed random variable with $p_1=\theta_1, p_2=(1-\theta_1)\theta_2, p_3=(1-\theta_1)(1-\theta_2)$ and the pmf

$$f_{X}(x_1,x_2,x_3) =  \displaystyle {n! \over x_1!\cdot x_2! \cdot x_3!} \cdot p_1^{x_1}\cdot  p_2^{x_2}\cdot p_3^{x_3},$$
$\text{when } \sum\limits_{i=1}^3 x_i=n \ \text{and} \ 0<p_i<1 \ \forall \  i\in \ \{1,2,3\}$